# combinatorial algorithms, merging series

Tags: analysis, algorithms, sorting, analysis-of-algorithms

who can help to solve this combinatorial algorithms problem**strong text**
Let M(n,m) denote the complexity of the best algorithm for merging of a1<..<an, b1<..<bm series. Prove that M(3,6) <= 7

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.